# QXmlQuery::evaluateTo() function returns empty list

Tags: qt, qt5.5, qxmlquery

I am trying to parse an XML file using the `QXmlQuery`. However when I run the `QXmlQuery::evaluateTo()` function I get back as a result an empty list.
My XML is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
    <trk>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="42.45612" lon="-5.45623">
                <ele>50.202291</ele>
                <time>...</time>
                <desc>lat.=42.45612, lon.=-5.45623, Alt.=50.202291m. Speed=12.225666m/h.</desc>
                <speed>4.121307</speed>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.166598" lon="-2.811355">
                <ele>47.236732</ele>
                <time>...</time>
                <desc>lat.=50.166598, lon.=-2.811355, Alt.=47.236732m. Speed=11.134823m/h.</desc>
                <speed>2.123456</speed>
            </trkpt>
         </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

And my code is the following:

```
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
       qDebug() << "Error: Cannot read file " << qPrintable(fileName)
                  << ": " << qPrintable(file.errorString())
                  << "\n";
    }
    QXmlQuery q;
    q.setFocus(&file);
    q.setQuery("//gpx/string()");
    bool valid = q.isValid();

    QStringList items;
    q.evaluateTo(&items);
    qDebug() << items;
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Wellcome to the club:-) I tried many times to understand or use QXMLQuery, but always failed wasting many hours learning it. I think, this is the one of least documented class of Qt.